# TFS 2017, build failing because of ssrs project into the solution

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I am creating build for solution which has 2 projects (ssis,ssrs and SSAS) i am getting below error. I think this is because of SSRS in the solution. I have taken VS build and passed MSBuild arguremnts: **/ignore:.dtproj,.rptproj**

Error messages:

```
Source\Main\BI\Advocaten.BI\SSRS Advocaten\SSRS Advocaten.rptproj(68):Source\Main\BI\Advocaten.BI\SSRS Advocaten\SSRS Advocaten.rptproj(68,11): Error MSB4226: The imported project "O:\Microsoft Visual Studio\MSBuild\Reporting Services\Microsoft.ReportingServices.MSBuilder.targets" was not found. Also, tried to find "Reporting Services\Microsoft.ReportingServices.MSBuilder.targets" in the fallback search path(s) for $(MSBuildExtensionsPath) - "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild" . These search paths are defined in "O:\Microsoft Visual Studio\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe.Config". Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk in one of the search paths.
Source\Main\BI\Advocaten.BI\SSIS Advocaten\SSIS Advocaten.dtproj(3):Source\Main\BI\Advocaten.BI\SSIS Advocaten\SSIS Advocaten.dtproj(3,3): Error MSB4067: The element <DeploymentModel> beneath element <Project> is unrecognized.
Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.
Source\Main\BI\Advocaten.BI\SSIS Advocaten\SSIS Advocaten.dtproj(3):Source\Main\BI\Advocaten.BI\SSIS Advocaten\SSIS Advocaten.dtproj(3,3): Error MSB4067: The element <DeploymentModel> beneath element <Project> is unrecognized.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Business Intelligence Semantic Model\1.0\Microsoft.AnalysisServices.VSHostBuilder.targets(71):C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Business Intelligence Semantic Model\1.0\Microsoft.AnalysisServices.VSHostBuilder.targets(71,7): Error MSB4062: The "Microsoft.AnalysisServices.VSHostBuilder.SemanticModelGetOutputFilesTask" task could not be loaded from the assembly O:\Microsoft Visual Studio\MSBuild\Business Intelligence Semantic Model\1.0\Microsoft.AnalysisServices.VSHostBuilder.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'file:///O:\Microsoft Visual Studio\MSBuild\Business Intelligence Semantic Model\1.0\Microsoft.AnalysisServices.VSHostBuilder.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.
Source\Main\BI\Advocaten.BI\SSRS Advocaten\SSRS Advocaten.rptproj(68):Source\Main\BI\Advocaten.BI\SSRS Advocaten\SSRS Advocaten.rptproj(68,11): Error MSB4226: The imported project "O:\Microsoft Visual Studio\MSBuild\Reporting Services\Microsoft.ReportingServices.MSBuilder.targets" was not found. Also, tried to find "Reporting Services\Microsoft.ReportingServices.MSBuilder.targets" in the fallback search path(s) for $(MSBuildExtensionsPath) - "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild" . These search paths are defined in "O:\Microsoft Visual Studio\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe.Config". Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk in one of the search paths.
Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.
```

Comment: if need ,ore details ..please let me know

Comment: Could you update with your `VSbuild` task definition here? Also, which agent are you using? Hosted agent?

Comment: You might want to install SSDT with RS, IS, AS for VS that match the VS version on your agent.  Even if you don't want to build them MSBuild might be trying to see if it can build or not and failing. Check here for SSDT RS, IS, AS https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver15